# In angular2, is it possible to get a count of subscribers to an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I imagine it would be possible to keep subscribing to an observable and forget to unsubscribe.  I suspect this is happening in my application.  Does the observable have a property that could give me a count of the subscribers hanging off it?

Comment: I think the closest you can get is to use .refCount(). https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md

Comment: I have answered based on your description you wish to have methods to not forget unsubscribing as I felt it was the core of your question. There are of course ways to write an operator that would actually help count, but this would be highly complex due to the way different operators might subscribe at different points of a stream and so on. Hopefully my answer will give you the tools you need without having to go into the meta-information of how many subscribers there is to an observable.

Answer (score 10):

While it is absolutely possible to forget to unsubscribe, and the leaks have consequences ranging from test runners that never end to memory leaks, angular2 has some tools and common patterns to manage its life-cycle.

angular2 provides a simple way not to forget. The simplest way, when used in templates, is to simply use the **async** pipe which will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe for you.

Otherwise, when you use the *.subscribe()* method, it returns a subscription. A common practice would be to capture injected dependencies in the constructor, make the necessary subscriptions of a component within **ngOnInit** and unsubscribe from within **ngOnDestroy**.

Sometimes, you will be subscribing to multiple observables. RxJS provides the class Rx.Subscription to group subscriptions together. It can be used in the following way:

```
const incomeSubscription = income$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
const expensesSubscription = expenses$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

const subscription = new Rx.Subscription();
subscription.add(incomeSubscription);
subscription.add(expensesSubscription);
```

Now calling *subscription.unsubscribe()* will unsubscribe any subscription still active.

Finally, it is important to understand that RxJS streams are unicast by default (unlike promises which always cache the results and are only multicast). This means in practice that each subscription actually becomes a new rx stream. In the case of "cold" observables like *Http.get()* for example, that each subscription will actually generate the data from scratch. So in the mentioned case with *Http.get()*, you will make a HTTP call for each subscription (or instance that uses the pipe async in the template).

This means that it is good practice to:

- Only use the async pipe in a container style component, and have dumb
  presentational components that know nothing of RxJS. This helps to
  only subscribe at the container level
- If sharing data among subscribers to use an operator like `.refCount()`
  in some cases or Subjects in others. This makes the stream multicast
  and subscribers share the same stream rather than each have their own
- With angular v4+, it has become a good practice to use the `| async` in combination with as secondaryName (`stream$ | async as streamData`) so within the container component, if you use the values of an observable more than once, you don't subscribe multiple times to the observable

Comment: With angular v4, it has become a good practice to use the `| async` in combination with `as secondaryName` (stream$ | async as streamData) so within the container component, if you use the values of an observable more than once, you don't subscribe multiple times to the observable .

Comment: Is the behavior (possible memory leak caused by too many subscriptions) the same for Angular 5.x.x?

Comment: @ThomasZoé as far as I know, you can get memory leaks in ng5 in the same way because of not unsubscribed subscriptions, not because of angular, but because of the wrong usage of rxjs. This is why I generally like to solve this problem at its source, and use the tools that automatically manage subscriptions, such as the filter *async*. An alternative I did not mention here is to use operators like *takeUntil* or *first* that also end a subscription as they end the stream after some condition is fulfilled (respectively condition true, or the first item is available from the stream)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I solved it by building an array of Subscriptions:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

private subValueChanges: Array<Subscription>;
```

Then each time I subscribe, push into the array:

```
this.subValueChanges.push(
  this.someControl.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .takeUntil(this.destroyValueChanges$)
      .subscribe (newValue => {...}
);
```

Then you know the length of the array is how many subscriber that 'someControl' has.

I don't recommend it as a solution but there are edge cases where this can be useful (of which I had one).

Also of interest is that a subscription has a flag 'closed' property that you can check - if it's closed, for example, you could remove it from the array. Alternatively, when you first subscribe, setup the `onunsubscribe` event to fire the removal of that particular subscriber from the array. Either way then your array will only contain active listeners - so it's length always tells you how many of them are out there! :)